# PHP skip script if not executed in 5 seconds

Tags: php

I have a problem with a php script that sometimes takes too long to be executed.
I'm searching for a way to break the script (skip it) if it takes more than 5 seconds and continue by executing the next command.

```
$browser  = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // the IP address to query
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
$loc = $query['isp'].' | '.$query['country'].' | '.$query['city'].' | '.$browser;
$first = strtok($loc, ')').")";
if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {
$loco = $first;
} else {
$loco = ' ---- ';
}
$file = "cfriplog.txt";
$txtfile = fopen($file, "a");
$line = $ip . " | " . date("d.m.Y | H:i:s", strtotime("$time"))." | ".$loco." | ".$page;
fwrite($txtfile, $line . "\n");
```

next script is here

Comment: what about the consequences of killing it half way though, do you need to roll back the changes? can you make it background task and not worry about the time it takes? does anything that comes after depend on this to have worked?

Comment: i am considering to make it a backgrond task. I'm thinking of using shell_exec